How can I make sure that unused bytes in a struct are zeroed out?
I have this structure:
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size=56)]
public struct SaveDataDialogNewItem {
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public IntPtr iconBuf;
    [FieldOffset(16)]
    public ulong iconSize;

    // [FieldOffset(24)]
    // [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=32)]
    // public byte[] reserved;
}

When I pass this to my c library, it seems that the 'reserved' part contains garbage data. On my desktop it get zeroed out, but in my prod environment it doesn't.
I have many structs and areas that just need to be zero. Is there a nice readable way to express this that doesn't require a lot of initialization code. If I just assigned a byte array that was all zeroed out, this would work, I already know that. But I want lower overhead when reading the code and in memory when allocating the struct.
tldr; how do I express that an area in memory should be initially zero?

The example code from the library that I'm using (c library) shows initialization like this: memset(&param, 0x00, sizeof(param));

You might be able to do something with the source generator LibraryImport approaching, using a custom marshaller
